# PHP - newline and BR removal

Tags: php, string

I have a string

```
"PRINT CHIFFON<BR /><BR />

"
```

I am trying to remove any newline symbols and 
 tags.

```
$i->colour_code = str_replace('<br>', '', strip_tags($i->colour_code));
$i->colour_code = str_replace('<br \/>', '', strip_tags($i->colour_code));
$i->colour_code = preg_replace("/[\n\r]/","",$i->colour_code);
```

That still does not work. Any ideas will be appreciated as this issue causes the whole system stop working

Comment: Sorry about wasting everyones time, the code I posted would work fine if str_replace is changed to str_ireplace that makes it case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to escape the slash in the second line of replacements. In fact, since you're running it through `strip_tags`, you don't even need the first two replacements. Try this:

```
$i->colour_code = str_replace(Array("\n","\r"),"",strip_tags($i->colour_code));
```

Just make sure that `$i->colour_code` is not readonly.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean it does not work? I just made a test and your code does indeed work, you have a problem with $i->colour_code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem okay to use preg_replace, I suggest using this line of code:

```
$i->color_code = preg_replace('/(<br>|<br ?\/>|\r|\n)/i', '', $i->color_code);
```

Unlike your examples, it will be case insensitive as well, so it doesn't matter if it is br or BR.

Comment: That's a nice piece of code, I decided to use str_ireplace but yours solution seems more elegant

Comment: Thanks. Since both mine and Kolinks answer are working solution to your problem, I suggest clicking on the checkbox to accept one of the answers :)